# Open Source Hardware For Air Gapped Computer?

Tags: hardware-wallet

I'm looking for vetted open source computer hardware that can run Armory air gapped.

Anyone know of such vetted hardware sources?

Comment: "Vetted" by whom, and to what standards?

Comment: An independent & trusted 3rd party, with a proven track record of exposing security flaws.

Comment: But to what standard? Do you care about, for example, TEMPEST attacks?

Comment: Yes of course.  I want the hardware to be vetted against all known NSA level attacks.